# Python file objects, closing, and destructors

Tags: python, file-io, destructor

The description of `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` says:

> If *delete* is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it
>   is closed.

In some circumstances, this means that the file is not deleted after the
Python interpreter ends. For example, when running the following test under
`py.test`, the temporary file remains:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import tempfile
import unittest2 as unittest
class cache_tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.dbfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    def test_get(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo', 'foo')
```

In some way this makes sense, because this program never explicitly
closes the file object. The only other way for the object to get closed
would presumably be in the `__del__` destructor, but here the language
references states that "*It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are
called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.*" So
everything is consistent with the documentation so far.

However, I'm confused about the implications of this. If it is not
guaranteed that file objects are closed on interpreter exit, can it
possibly happen that some data that was successfully written to a
(buffered) file object is lost even though the program exits gracefully,
because it was still in the file object's buffer, and the file object
never got closed?

Somehow that seems very unlikely and un-pythonic to me, and the open()
documentation doesn't contain any such warnings either. So I
(tentatively) conclude that file objects are, after all, guaranteed to
be closed.

But how does this magic happen, and why can't `NamedTemporaryFile()` use
the same magic to ensure that the file is deleted?

*Edit:* Note that I am not talking about file *descriptors* here (that are buffered by the OS and closed by the OS on program exit), but about Python file objects that may implement their own buffering.

Comment: This posts seems to contain a lot of assumptions and arguments, and very little actual questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Windows, NamedTemporaryFile uses a Windows-specific extension (os.O_TEMPORARY) to ensure that the file is deleted when it is closed.  This probably also works if the process is killed in any way.  However there is no obvious equivalent on POSIX, most likely because on POSIX you can simply delete files that are still in use; it only deletes the name, and the file's content is only removed after it is closed (in any way).  But indeed assuming that we want the file name to persist until the file is closed, like with NamedTemporaryFile, then we need "magic".

We cannot use the same magic as for flushing buffered files.  What occurs there is that the C library handles it (in Python 2): the files are FILE objects in C, and the C guarantees that they are flushed on normal program exit (but not if the process is killed).  In the case of Python 3, there is custom C code to achieve the same effect.  But it's specific to this use case, not anything directly reusable.

That's why NamedTemporaryFile uses a custom `__del__`.  And indeed, `__del__` are not guaranteed to be called when the interpreter exits.  (We can prove it with a global cycle of references that also references a NamedTemporaryFile instance; or running PyPy instead of CPython.)

As a side note, NamedTemporaryFile could be implemented a bit more robustly, e.g. by registering itself with `atexit` to ensure that the file name is removed then.  But you can call it yourself too: if your process doesn't use an unbounded number of NamedTemporaryFiles, it's simply `atexit.register(my_named_temporary_file.close)`.

Comment: For the Python 3 case: in 3.0, `io.BufferedWriter` is implemented in pure Python, and in Python 3.1 and later a pure Python implementation is still available as `_pyio`.  How can these modules use "custom C code"?

Comment: I don't know Python 3 in details, but I do know that the `_io` module is written in C at least in the current Python 3.x (Python 3.0 is old by now).  If there used to be a pure Python version, it was or is probably using `atexit`; if it was using `__del__` then it would be suffering from the same issues that this question is about.

Comment: @ArminRigo: you are talking about `io`, which is a C module. `_pyio` is the functionally equivalent, slow pure-Python version of `io` and also present in Python 3.3. And it doesn't use `atexit` either. Hmm. So maybe `_pyio` buffers cann actually be lost...

Comment: Ok, I just tried, and Python 3.3 always looses data, whether using _pyio or the built-in _io.  Running http://bpaste.net/show/94517/ ends up with the file 'foo' being empty, because of the self-reference that prevents its regular `__del__` from running promptly at interpreter exit.  As far as I can tell this is a nasty bug and I'll report it.

Comment: @ArminRigo: do you have a bug number, or the test script? Your bpaste link is 404 now..

Answer (score 1):

On any version of *nix, all file descriptors are closed when a process finishes, and this is taken care of by the operating system. Windows is likely exactly the same in this respect. Without digging in the source code, I can't say with 100% authority what actually happens, but likely what happens is:

- If `delete` is `False`, `unlink()` (or a function similar to it on other operating systems) is called. This means that the file will automatically be deleted *when the process exits and there are no more open file descriptors*. While the process is running, the file will still remain around.
- If `delete` is `True`, likely the C function `remove()` is used. This will forcibly delete the file before the process exits.

Comment: You're pretty close to correct here.  The normal means to handle anonymous temporary files is to open the file, immediately unlink it, then continue to use the file descriptor.  Normal Unix filesystems only reclaim the inode after the link count is zero AND the are not remain open file descriptors referring thereto.

Comment: @JimDennis Yeah, thanks, that's a more accurate description of what happens.

Comment: @Yuushi: I'm afraid this is wrong in several ways. 1) If `delete` is false, the file is not automatically deleted but remains after program exit. 2) The C `remove` function just calls `unlink`. There is no such thing is "forcibly delete". 3) I am talking about Python file *objects*, not file *descriptors*. While a file object generally has an underlying descriptor, I am worried about buffering happening inside the file object before data has been written to the descriptor.

Answer (score -1):

The file buffering is handled by the Operating System. If you do not close a file after you open it, it is because you are assuming that the operating system will flush the buffer and close the file after the owner exists. This is not Python magic, this is your OS doing it's thing. The `__del__()` method is related to Python and requires explicit calls.

Comment: That's not correct. There are several layers of buffering, and the OS layer is just one of them. Unless I misunderstand http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase, file objects may also be buffered at the Python level.